# bash read a file containing an array and save it as a new file list

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file that contains an array file.txt=["0", "1", "2", "3"] and I want to create a bash that reads the file and creates a new one as a list
file2.txt=

```
0
1
2
3
```

```
#!/bin/bash
value=$(<file.txt)
echo "$value"
echo ${#value[@]}
for key in ${value[@]}; do echo ${key}; done >> file2.txt
```

the result it is giving me is:

```
["0",
"1",
"2",
"3"],
```

Comment: Assuming your file really is JSON, `jq -r 'join(" ")' file.txt > fil2.txt`

Comment: Or just `tr -d '[]",' < file1.txt > file2.txt`

Comment: *Is* the array in JSON format? Before trying to figure out how to parse it, it's pretty important to know what format it's in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`json_pp`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/json_pp.1.html) to pretty print the array, then simply print only the digits using [`grep`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/grep).

```bash
cat file.txt | json_pp | grep -Po "\d+" > file2.txt
```

You can install [json_pp](https://command-not-found.com/json_pp) through Perl if it isn't already installed in your system.

**Edit:**

If your `file.txt` stores the array in the exact same format as you mentioned, then this one-liner would also work:

```bash
sed -E 's/^\["|"\]$//g; s/", ?"/\n/g' file.txt > file2.txt
```

Explanation: Remove the first `["` and the last `"]` part, then substitute every `", "` with a new line